# box-sizing border-box and borders on objects with unkown height & width

Tags: html, css

I have two input boxes that I want to highlight when selected.

I have the following global border-box styling applied:

```
/* box sizing */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

According to my knowledge when applying a border to any element, its width or height should now remain unchanged.

When applying the following style to my input boxes:

```
input{
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: none;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid $dark_blue_highlight;
}
```

...the size actually changes on selection.

I ended up trying to solve this for hours before I figured out the solution: explicitly defining height for the element. not width, only height works. I'm completely baffled.

I would really prefer to do this without defining a size, why is that not an option? Shouldn't this work on elements of unknown size?

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: A possible solution is set `border: 2px solid transparent;` and then on `focus` set `border-color: blue;`. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1ge44LsL/)

Comment: `border-box` tells the browser to include borders when painting an object with a **defined width** only AFAIK. Otherwise there is no calculation taking place.

Comment: actually defining height seems to be the only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`box-sizing` property works for elements with known dimensions. If there's no defined width/height, it's not going to work as you expect. It's there for those times you don't want elements with known dimensions to change. If you try setting height & width for your inputs, you'll realize nothing changes.